# Force experienced by magnets

Tags: electromagnetism

When two opposite poles of two different magnets are brought together, is it necessary that both of them experience equal repulsive force if one magnet is slightly weaker than the next?

Comment: Newton's third law.

Comment: The opposite poles attract, like poles repel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - as pointed out by DKNguyen in a comment, Newton's 3rd law implies that both magnets exert the same force on each other.

You can see the same effect in the electric force. From Coulomb's law, $F = kq_1q_2/r^2$. Even if $q_1 = 1000 q_2$, the force acting on both charges remains $1000 k q_2^2/r$.

Comment: And gravity as well.